# GatsbyJS - Using SVGs as pseudo background image in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, gatsby

This is something I have been toying around with for a little while but am now at a point in the project I am working in Gatsby where I need a little advice.

I am trying to use SVG's as pseudo background images, but having no avail so far.

SCSS code:

```
 &:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../../static/square-hollow-yellow.svg);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: -5%;
    right: 50px;
  }
```

What is returned when looking up the background image source within inspector.

```
url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)
```

Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Folder structure of project

```
- src
  - components
    - Heros 
      - hero-square.js (file of component)
    - sass
      - main.scss (stylesheet)
  - static
    - sqaure-hollow-yellow.svg (svg file)
  - templates
    - angel-in-action-single.js (where the component is being rendered/called)
```

Comment: Be aware that if the container of `&:after` is `static`, the pseudo element might be at a totally different position and therefore not visible.

Comment: Would you suggest placing them in a different folder?
As there is no "specific" reason they have to be in static, this was just something that I had read on the docs.

Comment: Sorry, I placed the folder outside, it is actually within the components directory. I'll have a look at including as base64 with google :)

Comment: Would a possible workaround be using something like `gatsby-plugin-react-svg` or `gatsby-plugin-svgr` to render the SVG as a component, then target it to do what I wanted through CSS?

Comment: Sorry, I can't either help you with gatsby nor react. Certainly someone else will know it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the background image just is not in the visible area of your containers. It is hard to tell with the provided snippet only. Escpecially since the `::after` is positioned absolutely.

```css
div{
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px
}

div::after{
    background-color: lime;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1643/1643587.svg");
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: -5%;
    right: 50px;
    background-position: 50% 50%
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Also note that you can use `background-size` and `background-position` to place the background. You do not require the `::after` just for that.

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1643/1643587.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%
}

.div1{
  background-color: green;
}

.div2{
  background-color: lime;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-position: -50px -5%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div class = "div1"></div>
<div class = "div2"></div>
```

Comment: I will add my structure to the original question :)

Comment: removing breaks compiler as it is unable to resolve file.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is using [`gatsby-plugin-react-svg`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/). It's really easy to use customize. You only need to take care of a few things and you can easily achieve what you want. In your gatsby-config.js:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
    options: {
      rule: {
        include: /assets/ 
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Keep in mind that `/assets/` is just a regular expression, not a path itself. If you want to use another folder (i.e: `/svg/`), you will need to set it like `include: /svg/`. No matter how deep is your folder.

Another thing to take into account is to have only SVG inside that folder and they must have a different `id` (usually exported SVG has a standard `id` and if they are repeated you will have troubles importing SVGs).

Once you have your set up ready, just import the SVG as a React component:

import Icon from "./path/assets/icon.svg";
// other code

```
return <div>
    <Icon className="myIcon" />
</div>;
```

You can now target the SVG and style it as you wish. If it's inside a `position: relative` container, you can easily apply the styles of the `::after` pseudoselector you've provided.

Comment: Cheers for the info and explanation  Yeah I’ve had that experience in the past with SVGs, `#Layer_1` on all of them. I’ll give this a shot, the pseudo targeting was actually to another element and using the SVG as a background image but I can just import it and `position: absolute` it :)